# IIS atuto change "Physical Path" to another after running for a minute

Tags: server, internals

Please help me!
Using IIS 10 in WS2016, my website running for a minute and then return "500 - Internal server error".

- Restarting the website (also IIS, Server) made it work and for a minute then the error occurred.
- Open the website right on the server but there is no more detailed error message.
- Enabled "Failed Request Tracking" for the website, added rules but nothing in View Tracking Log.

Today, by chance from another website in my iis, I found out that iis was automatically pointing the request to a different "Physical Path".

Folder A contains pageA.htm

Folder B contains pageB.htm

- At start, website point to folder A (due to Physical Path). I could open pageA.htm successfully
- After about 1 minute, if i open pageA.htm, i will receive the error message "The page could not be known due to internal server error". But now I could open pageB.htm successfully